# Steps to get access token for google drive account in apex

Tags: google-drive-api, access-token

I want to generate access token for my google drive and want to use that access token for creating folders in my google drive.
For folder creation I have written working code only issue is I am not getting access token for it.
Can anyone please tell me **how to get access token by using apex class and trigger**

Thanks

Comment: Is there any code you're working on? If that's the case, can you provide it?

Comment: Yes I am working on code but it is not working.

Comment: public String getToken (){
  String body = 'client_id='+cId+'&client_secret='+cSecret+'&username='+uname;
  Http h = new Http();
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setBody(body);
  req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');
  req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
  HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
  deserializeResponse resp1 =(deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
   return resp1.access_token;
}